# WPF Command Binding Child Parent Command Bubble

Tags: c#, wpf

WPF : I have an itemscontrol, and every item will have a close button. I want to implement in such a way that when button is clicked, first it should call the corresponding command of item and then it shud call the command binding of parent. Basically bubble from child to parent but it should fire at both child and parent.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for a RoutedCommand.  Josh Smith has a good explanation of how these work here: https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/03/18/understanding-routed-commands/